# react js import component only if previous component is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I have index.js file which is starting point of my react application. I am importing Login.js and Full.js file in index file. Here is my index.s file

```
import Login from './views/Login/Login';
import Full from './containers/Full/';

ReactDOM.render((<Provider store={store}>
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/" name="Login Page" component={Login}/>
     <Route path="/login/:AUTHKEY" name="Login" component={Login}/>
     <Route path="/" name="Home" component={Full}/>
   </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
</Provider>
),document.getElementById('root'));
```

In my Login.js page, i am receiving auth key in URL. e.g http://localhost:8080/#/login/123456

I am storing this authkey in localstorage.

I have one constant file which is imported in Full.js file, this constant file is common to all routing components. I am passing this localstorage authkey to Constant file. Then i use this authkey from Constant.js file in API calls.

Here is my Constant.js file (Imported in Full.js page)

```
let authkey = localStorage.getItem("AUTHKEY");
export default {
  AXIOSCONFIG:{
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
       'authKey':authkey
   }
  }
}
```

The problem is importing of Login and Full is asynchronous so when Login page loads, Full.js component also loads and then Constant.js file shows authkey as null (because authkey in localStorage is not set yet). I am trying to achieve is import Full.js component only if authkey is set to localStorage (this happens in Login.js page)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delay importing. The solution is to load `authkey` at the right point in time, after the localStorage item has been set:

```
var authkey;

export default {
  AXIOSCONFIG: {
    init: function() {
      authkey = localStorage.getItem("AUTHKEY");
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'authKey': authkey
    }
  }
}
```

Elsewhere, run `Constant.AXIOSCONFIG.init();` before making requests. You can also turn `headers` into a function that loads the authkey, then returns the headers.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a condition to the render of Full component.

```
<Route path="/" name="Home" component={() => localStorage.getItem("AUTHKEY") ? <Full /> : null }/>
```

Comment: But as far as I can see, that does not prevent `authkey` from being `null` though.

Comment: As I understand, @sameer-thite problem was the render of Full component. not the value of `authkey`. BTW, localStorage.getItem("AUTHKEY") will return null if the key does not exist in the locale storage.

Comment: If you look at the above Constant.js code, you can see that `authkey` is set at the very start, when `localStorage.getItem("AUTHKEY")` is still `null`, and never updated. This means what regardless of the state of `localStorage`, when `Constant.AXIOSCONFIG.headers` is used, `authkey` is `null`.